# Using sqlite with codeigniter strange error

Tags: php, sqlite, codeigniter, model

I am trying to use the sqlite database with codeigniter. I created a table in it and then loaded the database in the config file as;

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlite';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
```

And autoloaded the db library in autoload.php but the view that I render from the controller is blank even does not display any error. When I do not autoload this file then the viw renders correctly. I am not sure what is the problem here.

Comment: do you have errors turned on? `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: It has nothing to do with the view not rendering, its because you dont have errors displaying see @swatkins comment above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CI2 has changed a few bits. First of all you need the sqlite protocol and path in the 'hostname' parameter, and you need to set the dbdriver as 'pdo'. Oh, and you obviously need the PDO sqlite driver installed on the server:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'sqlite:/var/my.db';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
```

There is also a bug in the release I downloaded which casuses DB errors to be thrown incorrectly. If you have this, google the output with PDO exception and you should find the bug. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

you should check this out: [PDO SQLite3 in CodeIginter](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PDO_SQLite3)

Comment: This is for older version of codeigniter. It does not work with codeigniter2. Codeigniter itself has aqlite driver. I just wanted to why the view is just blank instead of showing some html in view file and why isn't it sjowing any error if there were error.